# Select duplicated items with non duplicates in the same collection

Tags: c#, linq, join

(Edited)

This is my code with examples of the collections I am working with:
That's what I meant when I wrote that `myProducts1` and `myProducts1`  are nested collections

```
List<MyProducts> myProducts1= {
new MyProducts{id = 1, Name = "product1", isExcl= true},
new MyProducts{id = 2, Name = "product2", isExcl= false},
new MyProducts{id = 3, Name = "product3", isExcl= true},
new MyProducts{id = 4, Name = "product4", isExcl= false}
}
List<MyProducts> myProducts2= {
new MyProducts{id = 5, Name = "product5", isExcl= true},
new MyProducts{id = 6, Name = "product6", isExcl= false}
}
IEnumerable<SelectedProductRequest> selectedProducts = {
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 1, Name = "product1", Price = 23},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 1, Name = "product1", Price = 44},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 2, Name = "product2", Price = 11},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 6, Name = "product6", Price = 34},
}

List<CategoryProduct> productsWithCategories = {
{CategoryName= "Category1", categoryProduct = myProducts1 },
{CategoryName= "Category2", categoryProduct = myProducts2 }
}
```

Here is my first code:

```
IEnumerable<SelectedProductViewModel> products1 = 
.GroupBy(categoryProduct => categoryProduct .CategoryName)
                .Select(categoryProduct => new ProductCategoryViewModel(
                    categoryProduct .Key,
                    categoryProduct 
.Select(product => new SelectedProductViewModel(
                            product.Name,
                            selectedProducts.FirstOrDefault(selectedProduct => selectedProduct.id== product.id)?.Price ?? 0,
                            product.IsExclusive))
                        .OrderByDescending(product => product.id)))
```

Here is my second code:

```
IEnumerable<SelectedProductViewModel> products2 = 
.GroupBy(categoryProduct => categoryProduct .CategoryName)
                .Select(categoryProduct => new ProductCategoryViewModel(
                    categoryProduct .Key,
                    categoryProduct
.Join(contractSelectedProducts, product => product.id, selected => selected.id, (product, selected) =>
                            new SelectedProductViewModel(
                            product.Name,
                            selected?.Price ?? 0,
                            product.IsExclusive))
```

The results I get with those pieces of code:

```
products1= {"Category1",{
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 1, Name = "product1", Price = 23, IsExclusive = true},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 2, Name = "product2", Price = 11, IsExclusive = false},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 3, Name = "product3", Price = 0, IsExclusive = true},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 4, Name = "product4", Price = 0, IsExclusive = false}
},
"Category2", {new SelectedProductRequest {id = 5, Name = "product5", Price = 0, IsExclusive = true},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 6, Name = "product6", Price = 34, IsExclusive = false}}

products2= {"Category1",{
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 1, Name = "product1", Price = 23, IsExclusive = true},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 1, Name = "product1", Price = 44, IsExclusive = true},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 2, Name = "product2", Price = 11, IsExclusive = false}
}},
"Category2", {new SelectedProductRequest {id = 6, Name = "product6", Price = 34, IsExclusive = false}
```

But the result I want to achieve is this:

```
products= {"Category1",{
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 1, Name = "product1", Price = 23, IsExclusive = true},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 1, Name = "product1", Price = 44, IsExclusive = true},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 2, Name = "product2", Price = 11, IsExclusive = false},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 3, Name = "product3", Price = 0, IsExclusive = true},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 4, Name = "product4", Price = 0, IsExclusive = false}
}},
"Category2",{
{new SelectedProductRequest {id = 5, Name = "product5", Price = 0, IsExclusive = true},
{new SelectedProductRequest {id = 6, Name = "product6", Price = 34, IsExclusive = false}
}
```

(edited code)

My question: How can I achieve this result without using `products1` and `products2`? Or how can i do it in a better way?

Comment: Well, you can use joins here as well

Comment: You want to combine to lists that are both SelectedProductRequest.  So you can do : products1.AddRange(products2);  You will get 7 items and then need to remove duplicates.

Comment: What is wrong with your code, which query doesn't work properly?

Comment: i just edited my code, so now I think it s more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated as per comment**

> Solution 1

I changed the last `Linq` query by :

```
List<ProductCategory> mergedList = products1
    // concat products2 with products1
    .Concat(products2)
        // group by category name
        .GroupBy(x => x.CategoryName)
            //dictionay(categoryName, list of SelectedProductRequests)
            .ToDictionary(key => key, value => value.SelectMany(x => x.SelectedProductRequests)
                 .GroupBy(x => new { x.id, x.Name, x.Price, x.IsExclusive })
                // take the first in grouped element
                .Select(x => x.First())
                //convert to SelectedProductRequest
                .Select(x => new SelectedProductRequest { id = x.id, Name = x.Name, Price = x.Price, IsExclusive = x.IsExclusive })
                .OrderBy(x => x.id)//order by id
                .ToList())
            .Select(x => new ProductCategory { CategoryName = x.Key.Key, SelectedProductRequests = x.Value })
            .ToList();
```

> Solution 2

if i understand your demand, you need to build `productsWithCategories` to get Expected result with one `linq` request, then check the following proposition by using `GroupJoin` instead `Join` :

```
IEnumerable<ProductCategoryViewModel> result = productsWithCategories
    .Select(x => new ProductCategoryViewModel
    {
        CategoryName = x.CategoryName,
        SelectedProductViewModels = x.categoryProduct
            .GroupJoin(selectedProducts, prd => prd.id, sel => sel.id,
                (prd, sel) => sel != null && sel.Any() ?
                sel.Select(y =>
                    new SelectedProductViewModel
                    {
                        id = prd.id,
                        isExcl = prd.isExcl,
                        Name = prd.Name,
                        Price = y.Price
                    }).ToList() :
                    new List<SelectedProductViewModel>
                    {
                        new SelectedProductViewModel
                        {
                            id = prd.id,
                            isExcl = prd.isExcl,
                            Name = prd.Name,
                            Price = 0
                        }
                    })
                    .SelectMany(z => z)
                    .ToList()
    });
```

i hope that will help you fix the issue

Comment: Thank you, but can you please take a look again on the question, I made an edit, that clarifies how I want to achieve the result. Thank you for your time

Comment: it's more complex now :), i have updated my answer, i hope that will give you the expected result.

Comment: thank you for your answer, Is it possible to do it in a better way? Without having to use  ``products1`` and ``products2`` , because I think it too much code , and maybe it could be done at once ? What do you think?

Comment: you're welcome, yeah we can do it by one ``linq`` request : can you check my second solution, i used just ``productsWithCategories`` and ``selectedProducts`` to build the expected result

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Concat` method to join arrays:

```
var selectedProductsMapped = selectedProducts.Select(s => new SelectedProductRequest
{
    id = s.id,
    Name = s.Name,
    Price = s.Price,
    isExclusive = myProducts.Where(p => p.id == s.id).FirstOrDefault().isExclusive
});

var exlcludedProducts = myProducts.Where(p => !selectedProducts.Any(sp => sp.id == p.id))
    .Select(s => new SelectedProductRequest
    {
         id = s.id,
         Name = s.Name,
         Price = 0                
    });

var result = selectedProductsMapped.Concat(exlcludedProducts);
```

An example:

```
var selectedProducts = new List<SelectedProductRequest> {
     new SelectedProductRequest {id = 1, Name = "product1", Price = 23},
     new SelectedProductRequest {id = 1, Name = "product1", Price = 44},
     new SelectedProductRequest {id = 2, Name = "product2", Price = 11}
};

var myProducts = new List<MyProducts> {
    new MyProducts{id = 1, Name = "product1", isExclusive= true},
    new MyProducts{id = 2, Name = "product2", isExclusive= false},
    new MyProducts{id = 3, Name = "product3", isExclusive= true},
    new MyProducts{id = 4, Name = "product4", isExclusive= false}
};


var selectedProductsMapped = selectedProducts.Select(s => new SelectedProductRequest
{
    id = s.id,
    Name = s.Name,
    Price = s.Price,
    isExclusive = myProducts.Where(p => p.id == s.id).FirstOrDefault().isExclusive
});

var exlcludedProducts = myProducts.Where(p => !selectedProducts.Any(sp => sp.id == p.id))
    .Select(s => new SelectedProductRequest
    {
         id = s.id,
         Name = s.Name,
         Price = 0                
    });

var result = selectedProductsMapped.Concat(exlcludedProducts);
```

Comment: Thank you, but Please can you take a look on the edit, the difficulty is that I am working on nested collections, otherwise I could use ``Concat()`` or ``Union()`` to just merge the two collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can produce the set of products1 and products2 with Linq's [`Union()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.8). You will need to implement `SelectedProductRequest`'s `GetHashCode()`.

```
products = products1.Union(products2);
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n3xMY3)

Add this to `SelectedProductRequest`:

```
public class SelectedProductRequest : IEquatable<SelectedProductRequest>
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Price {get;set;}
    public bool IsExclusive {get;set;}

    public bool Equals(SelectedProductRequest other) => other is null
        && this.id == other.id
        && this.Name == other.Name
        && this.Price == other.Price
        && this.IsExclusive == other.IsExclusive;

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as SelectedProductRequest);
    public override int GetHashCode() => (id, Name, Price, IsExclusive).GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think it was not clear when I wrote that I am working with nested collections, I have edited my question, now I think it's easy to know how I want to achieve the result.

Comment: @Mana I pass. Your last edit should be a new question.

Comment: No it is the same question, just added the full example and code so it makes clear that I am working with nested collections.